# Unable to simply create Theme in new ApachePOI XSSFWorkbook

Tags: xml, excel, themes, apache-poi, xssf

Is it is possible to create empty Theme if I create XSSFWorkbook by constructor XSSFWorkbook()? I can create new Theme, but not completely. I can create two entries in files content_types.xml and /xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels:

```
XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
POIXMLDocumentPart docThemePart = xssfWorkbook.createRelationship(XSSFRelation.THEME, XSSFFactory.getInstance(), 1);
```

Normally it’s not possible in ApachePOI, because it causes error. I had to MODIFY(!) ApachePOI ThemesTable class - I added constructor:

```
public ThemesTable() { super(); }
```

Then function above creates file /xl/theme/theme1.xml too, but it’s empty. How to fill this file? If I get Theme

```
ThemesTable theme = (ThemesTable) docThemePart;
```

and change it, content is not wrote to theme.xml. How to fill this file?
I checked Zip creating. Method marshall() in ZipPartMarshaller class gets input stream from some workbook parts. And for Theme input stream is empty. Maybe that’s the problem? When I tried (for tests) to create other object:

```
xssfWorkbook.createRelationship(XSSFRelation.CHART, XSSFFactory.getInstance());
```

everything was good.

What to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to override the `commit` method too

Your simplest bet is to grab a recently nightly build (until 3.13 beta 2 is out), then use the [StylesTable.ensureThemesTable() method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/StylesTable.html#ensureThemesTable()) to have an empty Themes Table added for you